# How do the angular tests for ngResource access internal function isValidDottedPath

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

When you look at the test cases for `ngResource` you see this:

```
describe('isValidDottedPath', function() {
  /* global isValidDottedPath: false */
  it('should support arbitrary dotted names', function() {
     expect(isValidDottedPath('')).toBe(false);
     expect(isValidDottedPath('1')).toBe(false);
```

How are they accessing the function `isValidDottedPath` inside these tests?  That function is defined internally inside the ngResource file.  Is it because they literally put that function on the global namespace?  And then I assume when they build and release it [here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.2/angular-resource.js) they wrap it in an IIFE and then those tests wouldn't be possible right?  It seems kind of dumb to put those functions in the global namespace for testing.

Comment: You are right with your assumptions but wrong with your attitude.

Comment: That came off as a little rude dude.  I'm not trying to say the angular team is dumb, I'm just trying to understand why this is a good place to put something on the global namespace

Comment: It's not on the global object when it is built as a module. Internally, each module could have global common functions, variables and constants . resource is only one file so it's not a good example but look at this file to understand the angular team design: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js

Comment: Ah.  Thank you.  That pointed me in the right direction @IlanFrumer